# Building a map for large datasets

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I have a very large file that has two columns and is ~10GB in size:

```
A  B
1  2
3  7
1  5
6  5
9  8
```

Essentially, I want to create a map like structure from this file as follows:

```
{{1 -> 2,5},{3->7}, {6->5}, {9->8}}
```

The goal is to write a function that calculates the percentage of unique values that are affected by removing a key. For example, in the above example, if I remove the key, 1, 2/4 of the values are affected. If I remove both 1 and 6, 2/4 of the values are affected. The problem is that this map structure will use too much memory. Are there any alternative approaches which are more efficient? I would think you would need a map in order to keep track of duplicates. You need to know which keys were already removed so you do not double count. Here is my initial code:

```
with open("C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Train.tsv") as f:
    counter = 0
    for line in f:
      #split line into key and value
      #add key into set
      #if set does not contain key
         #create new key
         #add list for this key
         #append value to this list
      #else
         #append value to already existing list for that key
```

This is the error message I get after running Alexander's code: not sure what KeyError 293 means

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-73145e080824> in <module>()
      7     for line in f:
      8         key, value = line.split()
----> 9         if value not in dd[key]:
     10             dd[key].append(value)
     11         counter = counter+1

KeyError: '293'
```

Comment: Are you expecting a lot of values that appear on only one key? You could save some memory by only tracking how many of those a key has, rather than exactly what the values are.

Comment: What are the actual ranges of the two columns? Are they guaranteed to be integers? Small integers? Characters?

Comment: The types of both should be integers. Also, if I don't know the exact values and only know the frequencies for each key, it would be difficult to get the coverage as I would be double counting since it it possible for different keys to have the same values.

Comment: What if you had duplicate values for a given key? Do you want to retain both, or just the set?

Comment: @Alexander I just want to to keep the unique values for each key.

Comment: How much memory are you working with, anyway?

Comment: Do you need to be able to distinguish keys with a single value no other key has from keys that don't appear in the dataset at all? If not, you could save memory by not storing keys that only have a single, unshared value.

Comment: I want to keep all keys. I want the ability to remove any key even if the key has one value not shared by an other key.

Comment: No, you would still have that ability. It's just that if you tried to remove a key that isn't in the dataset, you'd think it had a value.

Comment: Are there any limits on the sizes of these integers? You could save memory by using [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) arrays to store the values associated with a key.

Comment: I know that the the keys and values are integers but don't know beforehand the limits on the sizes of these integers.

Comment: @Alexander I did that thanks and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#!python3

from collections import defaultdict

AB_map = defaultdict(set)
Values = set()

with open('train.tsv') as infile:
    headers = next(infile)
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        a,b = map(int, line.split())
        AB_map[a].add(b)
        Values.add(b)

print("# of keys:", len(AB_map.keys()))
print("# of values:", len(Values))

def impact_of_deletion(keylist):
    values_impacted = set([])
    for key in keylist:
        values_impacted.update(AB_map[key])
    return values_impacted

for hyp in ((1,), (1,6)):
    print("Deleting", hyp, "would impact:", len(impact_of_deletion(hyp)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use defaultdict for this, which we will set to automatically assign each key an empty list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

filename = "C:/Users/XX/Desktop/Train.tsv"
dd = defaultdict(list)
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split(',')  # Assuming comma delimited.
        if value not in dd[key]:  # If you only want to retain unique values.
            dd[key].append(value)
```

Comment: This doesn't really help with the memory issues.

Comment: It should. First of all you read the file line by line instead of on bulk. Second,  you are saving unique values per key instead of all of them. There is not much else that could be done without saving the results to a database or file.

Comment: @Alexander @zorny I think it should be rather `dd = defaultdict(list)`. I guess this solves the `KeyError` problem.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for that.